# Which model fit best for semi sinusoidal data?

Tags: numpy, statistics, analytics, modeling, linear-regression

I am having a record containing the maximum and the minimum monthly temperatures at a particular station. The record shows information for each month from January 1908 to March 2012. However, some of the temperature values have been blanked out.

```
Sample Data    
    yyyy    month   tmax    tmin
    1908    January 5.0 -1.4
    1908    February    7.3 1.9
    1908    March   6.2 0.3
    1908    April   Missing_1   2.1
    1908    May Missing_2   7.7
    1908    June    17.7    8.7
    1908    July    Missing_3   11.0
    1908    August  17.5    9.7
    1908    September   16.3    8.4
    1908    October 14.6    8.0
    1908    November    9.6 3.4
    1908    December    5.8 Missing_4
    1909    January 5.0 0.1
    1909    February    5.5 -0.3
    1909    March   5.6 -0.3
    1909    April   12.2    3.3
    1909    May 14.7    4.8
    1909    June    15.0    7.5
    1909    July    17.3    10.8
    1909    August  18.8    10.7
```

I want to find out the Missing values. Which model suits best for this kind of problem ? I am trying using MultiVariate Linear Regression here. Is it a right approach ?

Comment: There are many choices here. Essentially each different imputation method corresponds to a different assumption about how successive values are related. It's probably best to make explicit assumptions about those relations and derive the method from that; that would be a Bayesian inference approach. Aside from that, probably local regression methods such as LOWESS and Gaussian process regression are suitable. GP regression is actually quite simple and can yield an uncertainty for each value as well as a point estimate. Web searches for any of these terms should turn up a lot of hits.

Answer (score 0):

This is an empirical question. Linear regression is a good starting point. If the data have non-linear shape you might find transforming features/outputs allows you to fit a linear model.

I'd suggest you come up with something, and use cross validation on the entries with present values. Use this to improve your method. If it is reasonable to assume that missing values have the same distribution as present values (i.e. there isn't some systematic bias, like equipment malfunction in extreme temperatures, in the missing values) then cross validation error ought to be a reasonable way to judge the quality of your missing data imputation.